# Stop Processes on JVM Kill

Tags: java, process, jvm, runtime, kill

In my code I execute and save the reference of a Process:

```
PROCESS = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqld ... ");
```

To kill this process, on JVM exit I made:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            PROCESS.destroy();
        }
    });
```

And the "forked" process stops only when the JVM correctly ends.

But when I drastically Kill the JVM Process, e.g. stop the IDE (Eclipse) debugger or kill from the Windows task manager, the "forked" process is still alive.

Is there any way to stop the process created from Runtime when the JVM Accidentally stops without completion?

Thank you

Comment: you are asking how to terminate a child process from within a process that is being killed after it has been killed?

Comment: No, I ask: how to kill a process created by a JVM instance when the instance itself is killed?